# custom serialization/deserialization using JSON .net

Tags: .net, json

My application receives SMS in following format:

STA:000000,000;L:310;TM:090516195102;D:1;T:01;C:25;A00:0.166;A01:00000;A02:0.578;A03:00
000;A04:00000;A05:00000;A06:00000;A07:00000;A08:00000;A09:00000;A10:00000;A11:00000;A1
2:00000;A13:31.00;A14:30.93;P01:00000000;P02:00000000;P03:00000000;P04:00000000;P05:000
00000;P06:00000000;K01:13333330000000000;O01:0000;8F

I want to deserialize this string to an object.  I already have read about JSON tool, but I don't know if I serialize and deserialize in this format. That is, can I change the default delimiter(`,`) and class(`{}`) and array notations(`[]`)?

Comment: That isn't json - why do you want to use a json serializer? It would be better to simply tell us what the rules are for that format, so we can offer guidance. But my guidance: forget json - that isn't json.

Comment: The format looks just like delimited key-value pairs, but it is hard to see what you want that to look like as an object... Do you have an example interpretation? i.e. What does that data represent?

Comment: tanks for your comments. these pair-value are output of a gprs data logger that sent via sms. considering the structure of string is not consistent (i.e some pair/values are omitted some times), what is the best way to read such a string to object (deserialize)? tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a `;` separated list of key-value pairs to me, where key and value are separated by `:`. The following code parses is as such. I don't see what this has to do with JSON.

```
const string testInput="STA:000000,000;L:310;TM:090516195102;D:1;T:01;C:25;A00:0.166;A01:00000;A02:0.578;A03:00"+
        "000;A04:00000;A05:00000;A06:00000;A07:00000;A08:00000;A09:00000;A10:00000;A11:00000;A1"+
        "2:00000;A13:31.00;A14:30.93;P01:00000000;P02:00000000;P03:00000000;P04:00000000;P05:000"+
        "00000;P06:00000000;K01:13333330000000000;O01:0000";

IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> ParseList(string input)
{
    string[] lines=input.Split(';');
    foreach(string line in lines)
    {
        string[] parts=line.Split(':');
        if(parts.Length!=2)
            throw new InvalidDataException(line);
        yield return new KeyValuePair<string,string>(parts[0],parts[1]);
    }
}

void Main()
{
     ParseList(testInput).Dump();       
}
```

It doesn't handle the last `;8F` but I assume that's only an artifact of a truncated message.

Comment: tanks for your reply, assume that i have a class with STA, L, TM , D ,... properties. and i know some times in above string some of pair values are omitted, know what is the best practice to read such a string to class?